# MEAN Stack Angular HttpClient baseurl

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-httpclient

I was exploring the MEAN Stack project on GitHub and I just realize that the Angular auth service from their GitHub doesn't use any base URL. They just use `/api/auth/login` as URL in HttpClient.post for example.

How can be possible as there is no have an HttpInterceptor to add a base URL ?

Answer (score 0):

By default Angular will put this after the project's URL. So instead of going to `/api/auth/login` it will go to `https://<projecturl>/api/auth/login` or if working in local host `http://localhost:4200/api/auth/login`.

Here's a stackblitz which demonstrates this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cbtroa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts